# Why does MATLAB use column-major order?

Tags: c, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I understand that the C language uses row-major order to store arrays, whereas MATLAB uses column-major order.

Is there any specific reason for MATLAB choosing column-major order? Does MATLAB gain significantly by opting to arrange multidimensional arrays by column in memory (i.e. columns are contiguous)?

Comment: This guy says because Fortran: http://www.quora.com/Why-does-MATLAB-use-column-major-order-instead-of-row-Major-order-as-prevalent-in-C

Comment: C uses no order at all. When declaring two-dimensional arrays, it is up to the programmer to decide which dimension that is the rows and which is the columns. The only thing C guarantees is that the items of the right-most dimension of the array are stored in adjacent memory in relation to each other, and the left-most dimension is used to index those items. The programmer can then decide to access the array as `arr[col][row]` or `arr[row][col]`, and that's what decides the order, not something in the C language.

Comment: @Lundin, But, buy convention, first dimension is rows and second is columns.

Comment: @LuisMendo Not as far as I know. I've seen both versions used in various libraries, without noticing that one style is more common than the other.

Comment: @Lundin I mean mathematical (matrix) convention. I didn't know there are libraries that go against that convention. Weird!

Comment: @LuisMendo Again, the C language doesn't care about mathematical conventions. For example, you are free to declare a 3D matrix as `arr[y][x][z]` or in any other manner.

Comment: @Lundin But that's just notation. Calling the first index `y` doesn't _make_ it columns.

Comment: @LuisMendo Calling the first index "col" and treating it as a column makes it a column. There are no columns hidden inside your computer, yearning to be released. There are just memory cells that may or may not be charged to a voltage, and a screen which can lit pixels. To turn those things into a column, the programmer has to define what a column is, because neither the computer nor the C language has got a clue about that. Anyway, I doubt this discussion is helpful for the OP :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB uses column-major order for historical reasons.

Very early versions of MATLAB were implemented in FORTRAN and relied heavily on the LINPACK and EISPACK FORTRAN libraries which, unlike C, use column-major order. Even though it was (mostly) converted to a C implementation when it was initially commercialized, it retained the use of column-major order.

As far as I know there are no inherent advantages or disadvantages to column- or row-major arrays, it's just a choice that needs to be made one way or the other.